# customize the django admin panel?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to change the django bydefault admin panel title bar where wirte the **django administration**.
Actually I want to replace the **django administration** with the my site name.

Comment: Duplicate of all of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdjango%5D+admin+customize.

Comment: you right but i only want to replace the string "django administration"

Answer (score 6):

I found out the solution:
Make the file in notpad

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {% trans 'Your Customize name' %}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">{% trans 'Your Customize name administration' %}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

and then save the above file with the name "base_site.html" in the folder name "admin" of your project directory. 
Also give the path of admin parent directory in the settings.py file under TEMPLATE_DIRS in inverted commas.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look a django-grappelli : http://code.google.com/p/django-grappelli/

Or

Do it yourself : http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

Comment: @S.Lott - Thanks, that's the link I was looking for :)

Comment: You might want to delete the other "obsolete" link.